# How to get the control path property of a user control?

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control which is hosted in a content placeholder.

This is just 1 scenario, but the user control gets used all over the site.

The user control is responsible for generating a JSON request, and to my horror I'm noticing that the form element id's / names aren't what I've called them - instead prefixed by controlID_ContentPlaceHolderID_UserControl_MyActualFormElementName

I know I can turn this off if I was using .net v4, but the project is v2.

Please can you tell me how to grab the control path in the code behind, and by this I mean dynamically determine the ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_UserControlID part.

I could then create another form element -> post through the name -> and then server side after the post, know what my form elements are.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ClientId should get you somewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the top of my head, without testing, for the given user control recursively find the first control in the parent chain, during the return trip, buildup the 'path' for every [ClientId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx);

```
public string ClientIdPath(Control ctl)
{
     if (ctl.Parent !=null ) 
     { 
         return = string.Format("{0}_{1}", ClientIdPath(ctl.Parent), ctl.ClientId ); 
     }
     else
     {
         return ctl.ClientId;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice idea, traversing up the tree using recursion till you hit the top. Not sure if the code is 100%, but it will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should only use the `CliendID` whenever you are referring to a control in javascript.

[ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) in the name of the control in javascript. It is present in every web control.

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id
>   attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID
>   property. The ClientID value is often used to access the HTML element
>   in client script by using the document.getElementById method.

It combines the names of the parent controls to generate a unique id for the element in javascript.